# Unity: Blender's Armature messes up Faces

Tags: unity, blender, skeletal-animation, normals

The Model itself is fine when imported but when I activate the Animation all Normals and lighting get Inverted from the Bones.

Result:

[image: Result]

Import Settings:

[image: Import Settings]

Import Settings:

[image: Import Settings]

Blender Armature Settings:

[image: Blender Armature Settings]

Blender Export Settings:

[image][image]

Comment: Might wanna add that the normals are correct inside blender at all times. Is this an export bug or is the problem within unity? Anyway I could narrow down the problem?

Comment: First thing Animation system is totally different form your mesh render. Animation works on your rig . So I'm not sure is it work but try to uncheck the import material option and the try to make an material and assign it on mesh renderer . Use PBR material.

Comment: That didn't work. I mentioned in the final picture, I have attached a simple cube to the armature and imported it into unity with no materials or anything. Anything initially attached to the armature shows the same behaviour. The animation doesn't have to be running for the issues to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a transformation on the rig in blender, that is being applied to the mesh upon export (or upon animating). In the 3D view port open the properties window with 'N', and check if there is a un-applied transform. i.e rotation != (0, 0, 0) or scale != (1, 1, 1)

To apply the transformation, select the rig (in object mode) then hit ctrl-A, do the same with the mesh (just in case). If that doesn't help, try clearing the transformation(s) with alt-R, alt-G, and alt-S, for rotation, translate and scale respectively. [Blender docs](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Reset_Object_Transformations)

If this doesn't fix your issue, then just hack around the bug. Invert all the normals with Ctrl-N and export it like that haha

Comment: I have done all that and it's certainly not where the problem lies. The problem lies in the **ARMATURE** and only the **armature**. You did not read through my question properly. Read the red text on the pictures.

Comment: Rig == armature. I did read it properly, quite thoroughly actually. Can you send me the blend file, I'd like to have a look

Comment: oh.. I apologize. Seems like I was the one not reading properly. Yes your solution worked. The model no longer is inverted. However the entire model/rig is now twisted and warped. If you know how to fix the transform without destroying the entire animation I'd be greatful. The bounty is yours anyway. And a free Mac10.

Comment: It's much trickier to fix than I thought it would be. I thought I was done, but it was mirror flipped, which looked fine until I realised the bolt was on the wrong side of the gun....

Comment: Really sorry, but it's beyond my abilities to fix. The only suggestion I have is to invert the normals in blender, OR start from scratch. Maybe someone at blender.stackexchange.com could come up with a better solution